# Evaluating tree model height before and after fire in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, aster, time-series

I have downloaded **ASTER** images of one area in Aosta Valley. In 2008 fire occured. I have images from 2006 to 2016. How can I estimate the vegetation, precisely tree height before and after the fire?

[image: Aosta Valley 2006] [image: Aosta Valley]